# deshabilitar zoom en chrome bajo w7

Tags: javascript, windows, cakephp, google-chrome, extensión-google-chrome

tengo una aplicación desarrollada en cakephp, que se ejecuta en chrome en modo kiosco, es como un catálogo de productos. Cambiamos la pantalla de touchscreen porque tenía desgaste y problemas, y si bien la nueva es por infrarojo, mucho mejor, perdí o me cambiaron 2 funcionalidades importantes.
1) El zoom del chrome me genera complicaciones varias, alguna forma de anular esa funcion ?
2) Hay un slide que está encriptado y antes funcionaba, con el nuevo touch dejó de desplazarse con el dedo, alguien con similar experiencia que me de alguna idea de como mejorarlo sin tocar el código ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Puede que esto te sirva solo cambiando los css, meterle un zoom inicial

```
body, html{
  zoom: 100%;
}
```

tambien puedes probar de poner un `overflow: auto` sobre el div que contiene el slide encriptado

A parte tienes la etiqueta meta para inhabilitar el zoom o escalar la pagina al movil

```
<meta content='width=device-width; initial-scale=1.0; maximum-scale=1.0; user-scalable=0;' name='viewport' />
```